# How to fix broken data microusb on raspberry pi zero

Tags: usb, pi-zero

I have a raspberry pi zero 1.3 with a broken microusb data port. Before it broke power was supplied from an elegoo dc converter that can be attached to the breadboard. The converter can be powered both by a 9V power supply and by a 9v battery, converting the 9v input to 5v or 3.3v. The raspberry was powered by the 5v rail provided by the dc converter.

It had an ir sensor and a digital monitor connected to the pins as well as a wifi adapter connected to the usb. Everything worked fine with the 9V charger provided, but when I tried powering it up with a 9V battery the wifi adapter and the microusb connector stopped working.

The wifi adapter is gone, I'd like at least to save the raspberry.

I tried moving the sd card to another raspberry and everything worked fine. I tried to boot the broken one and the led was 'normal'. I tried editing editing the config file to ssh it from the usb following this tutorial: https://desertbot.io/blog/ssh-into-pi-zero-over-usb. While the same sd card worked fine on the working raspberry, I couldn't connect to the broken one via usb.

Would it be possible to identify the problem and fix it? It would be ok also to solder an external usb connector to the raspberry gpio or directly to the board. In this case is there a way to verify beforehand if the new connector will work?

Answer (score 0):

You can not feed 9V into a Raspberry Pi and expect it to keep working.

Anything over 5.5V is risky.  9V is fatal.

You will need to buy a new Pi.

Comment: Sorry I didn’t make it clear, the 9->5v adapter was the same for both the 9v power supply and the 9v battery, so the output level was 5v in both cases, at least on paper

Answer (score 0):

Why don't you ask someone in your city to replace the broken USB connector?.

Also it is worth pointing out that no data remains on the Pi itself (some does, but it  is not the case explaining it here), so you can keep using the same microSD on another Pi no worries.

Besides all that, what was your question again?